# Why does missing "require" / "include" call error_handler an extra time?

Tags: include, require, php, php-internals

I have a custom error handler set up using [`set_error_handler`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php). When I tried to include a file that doesn't exist, PHP calls error_handler one more time than it should:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
set_error_handler(function($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, $errcontext){
    if(error_reporting() !== 0){
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<br>In Custom Error Handler...";
        echo "<br>Err String: ", $errstr;
        echo "<br>Passing to Default Handler...";
    }
    return false; // allow default
});
include("/missing_file.php"); // line 11
?>
```

Output:

> **In Custom Error Handler...** // this is the extra error handler call
>
> Err String: include(/missing_file.php)
>   [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>
> Passing to Default Handler...
>
> // the default handler does nothing, even though error_reporting is not zero
>
> // Next Phase:
>
> **In Custom Error Handler...**
>
> Err String: include() [function.include]: Failed
>   opening '/missing_file.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')
>
> Passing to Default
>   Handler...
>
> **Warning**: include() [function.include]: Failed opening
>   '/missing_file.php' for inclusion
>   in
>   **/home/yccom/public_html/apr/test.php** on line **11**

The same behavior is observed with [`require`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php).

For example, changing line 11 to `require` will give this output:

> **In Custom Error Handler...** // this is the extra error handler call
>
> Err String: require(/missing_file.php) [function.require]: failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory
>
> Passing to Default Handler...
>
> // the default handler does nothing, even though error_reporting is
>   not zero
>
> // Next Phase:
>
> **Fatal error**: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/missing_file.php' in **/home/yccom/public_html/apr/test.php** on
>   line **11**

What may be causing the error handler's additional call?

Comment: Try to use `include_once()` to see if the same behaviour appears.

Comment: Does the file `some_file.php` exist in the same directory as this file?

Comment: @Tro, no it doesn't exist anywhere.

Comment: @Arthur, include_once only gives 2 errors. The first line, and the last line.

Comment: tested your code, only got the last 2 errors, which is normal.

Comment: @Pacerier: Then your include might be executed 3 times (several includes, loops, etc.)

Comment: @Flosculus, then what's the explanation for the 4 errors?

Comment: @Arthur, how so? The code above is the *complete* code. Which line is culprit, in particular?

Comment: @Pacerier: If it's really the complete code, I've no idea... Same errors as Flosculus here: http://workspace.hoa.ro/SO17617188/index.php

Comment: @Arthur, even if it's 2 errors, how is 2 errors *normal*? The manual didn't say anything about emitting 2 errors.

Comment: @Pacerier One error for failed file stream, and another for failed include.  Granted, the first error does cause the second error, but because `include` performs the tasks to `load the file` and `process the code`, both errors occurred as a result of the file not existing.

Comment: @Flosculus, since you said that this is *expected* behavior, wouldn't this kind of behavior be documented?

Comment: @Pacerier I've just dug in a bit further, the first error is failed to load the stream for the `file path` you specified, then it attempts to load the file from the `include paths`.  Its basically telling you that it a) couldn't find the file at the requested path, and b) couldn't find it at any of the alternative include paths.

Comment: @Flosculus, but there is only one path in the include_path. This doesn't explain the 4 errors. Even if there are 10 paths in the include_path, it is still 4 errors.

Comment: @Pacerier I was only explaining the reason for the `2 errors` that I see, regarding the 4 errors, I would follow Elias, imo if it is not caused by a loop, and the code I tested is under the same conditions as the code you showed, I'd put my money on something in php.ini or version.

Comment: @Flosculus, I'm using 5.3.26, there's no loop, that's the complete page. My php.ini: http://goo.gl/Z6YKY

Answer (score 2):

It's quite simple, really. PHP's lifecycle consists of 4 distinct phases:

1. Parsing
2. Compilation
3. Scanning
4. Execution

for your code to be parsed, all files that are included/required need to be fetched in the first phase, to translate the code into meaningful expressions. Your file doesn't exist, so a warning is issued.
Next, the compilation phase encounters the same `include` statement, and tries to convert the expressions into opcodes. The file doesn't exist, so a warning is issued.
Scanning translates code into tokens, which again cannot be done for the missing include file. 
Execution time... The file cannot be executed because it is missing.

Why would PHP work like this? Isn't it stupid to blunder along, eventhough a file is missing? 
In a way, yes, but `include` is used to include files that are non-critical to the script, if you really *need* that file's contents, you use `require` (but preferably `require_once`). The latter emits, as you stated, a *fatal* error, and stops everything dead in its tracks. That's what should happen if you're depending on another file for your code to function.

The `require` construct issues an `E_COMPILER_ERROR`, which effectively halts the compiler (not unlike `__halt_compiler`) at a given offset(the line where the failing `require` statement resides).

[Check these slides](http://www.slideshare.net/ravirajforyou/how-php-works) for more details on each of the 4 main phases.

The reason why your code emits four warnings, is simply because PHP tries to include the file four times. Try running the script from the command line, but use `strace`:

```
$ strace -o output.txt php yourScript.php
```

open the output file, and see the internals of the Zend engine. Pay special attention to lines that look like:

```
lstat("/your/path/./file.php", 0x50113add8355) = -1//0x5... ~= 0xsomeaddress
```

You'll see where PHP goes looking for the file: it's all its `include_path` directories, the `cwd`, `/usr/share/php`, probably a pear or lib directory, and the include path you explicitly set.
I've gotten the idea to do this from [this site](http://www.developerknowhow.com/a-brief-look-inside-phps-zend-engine/), and based on the output I got, this seems to me to be the most plausible explanation as to why you see multiple errors.

Comment: Your answer implies that `require` would only throw a single error and exit. But even a `require` throws 4 errors (the first 3 being the same, and the fourth a fatal). Why does PHP blunder along even though files that are critical to the script are missing.

Comment: @Pacerier: I'm not _that_ familiar with the ZendEngine, but my guess would be that PHP, to generate the output (the fatal error) still has to go through all 4 steps, but I'm looking into that now

Comment: @Pacerier: Try the same thing without the custom error handler, then you _should_ see a difference between include and require

Comment: regarding your answer's last paragraph, that is simply not true. E_COMPILER_ERROR will not be handled with the custom error handler. see http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php. The only way E_COMPILER_ERROR can be handled is through register_shutdown_function http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277224/how-do-i-catch-a-php-fatal-error

Comment: @Pacerier: I've done some more digging, and I think I've found the reason why you get 4 errors instead of the expected 1. Editted my answer, and added a link that goes into more detail. +1 for your question, it's been fun getting back _"down and dirty"_ with the zend engine's internals

Comment: thanks for the update. But I'm still not convinced this is the answer. For some reason no matter how many paths I have in my include_path, the number of error handler calls are the same. I'm still trying to dig more into it...

Comment: @Pacerier: Have you tried using system trace, to check what include paths are being used?

Comment: I'm hosting on a virtual server and do not have access to system trace (unless you mean another thing). I've narrowed down the problem using error_reporting and absolute paths (thus offsetting include_path), take a look at the update.